# 2 similar looking "update" variants work different

Tags: python, sqlite

Here is snapshot #1:

```
strr = "UPDATE fileinfo SET file_name = ? WHERE md5sum = ?"
cr.execute(strr, ( rec[0], rec[1]) )
```

and #2:

```
strr = "UPDATE fileinfo SET file_name = {0} WHERE md5sum = {1}".format(rec[0], rec[1])
cr.execute(strr)
```

The first one works fine while the second one fails. It throws

> sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized
>   token: (some token in rec[0], depends on input data, might be "@" or "!" or whatever string you pass to input)

python 3.2, win7

Thank you.

Comment: It would help if you edited your question to give a sample of the input values that are causing the problem. Mind you, I suspect a simple `foo` and `bar` would exhibit it…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Warning! Bad code follows!***

The issue is that in your second example you're not supplying the strings as SQL strings but rather as literal values. That's very unlikely to work! Instead, you'd have to do this:

```
strr = "UPDATE fileinfo SET file_name = '{0}' WHERE md5sum = '{1}'".format(rec[0], rec[1])
cr.execute(strr)
```

Notice the additional single quotes? That's SQL string syntax.

### *But don't do this!*

The problem is if the strings you're substituting in have characters in them that are understood by the SQL parser as anything other than a literal character inside a string context. The most obvious example is `'` (the single quote character) itself. While you might be safe enough for the md5sum parameter, odd things do crop up in filenames (especially where non-technical users are involved!) so it's better to be careful at the beginning.

It's possible to handle this by adding extra magical quoting to the values during substitution, but it's easy to get wrong (a problem in vast numbers of PHP programs even to this day) and it's *doing it the wrong way* given that we have a better, simpler solution in the use of a prepared statement.

It's also slow. Using a prepared statement (i.e., your first example) is faster because the SQL engine can parse the code *once* instead of each time, and the values to be injected can be handled by effectively placing them in the right slot of the generated bytecode. There's never a need to recompute the query plan (i.e., the small program that SQLite creates inside itself) and the values themselves are never fussed around with; they're just faithfully used in the right way.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I don't use the second variant, i just was courious why it doesn't work (because formally it should). Now i see, the problem is that rec[0/1] contain non-integer data which should be wrapped with quotes. I

Answer (score 1):

The two variants you show are very different. In the first, you are using the database api to fill in the parameters - the values are being properly escaped.

In the second variant, you just use pythons string formatting to add the variables to the SQL string - values are not escaped and depending on the contents of `rec[0]` and `rec[1]` you will have malformed SQL.

Note also, that this is the path to SQL injection vulnerability!

Comment: I don't argue that the second one variants is well-formed, i don't understand why exactly these two variants work different **having same data**. rec[0] and rec[1] are the same for both variants.

Comment: But Daren just explained why: because in the first one, the db api escapes the values, and in the second one, it doesn't.

Comment: @Daniel: But it doesn't escape the values in the first case. It routes them in by a method that doesn't require escaping them and which doesn't involve parsing them at all. Much faster and much safer than escaping.